# why importing CSSRulePlugin in Next.js results in error?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, gsap

I am trying to use GSAP library in my Next.js project i downloaded the npm version of the library 
from [react jsap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-gsap).

but when i import it like this:

```
import { gsap } from "gsap";
import { CSSRulePlugin } from "gsap/CSSRulePlugin";
```

it throws an error, the error seems to be caused by CSSRulePlugIn since when i remove it from imports everything is fine.

the error:

[image]

Comment: You can animate in react using just GSAP (not react-gsap) if you'd like. There's a super helpful [installation page](https://greensock.com/install) on the GreenSock website that helps you get things installed and imported correctly.

Comment: @ZachSaucier oh thank you, actually i didn't know i could do that, will try that out in future for sure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

apparently this error occurs because GSAP tries to access the `window` element of the client browser but since i was using it in Next.js (SSR) so it would result in that error since there was no `window` to get a hold of.

so i ended up solving the problem by importing `CSSRulePlugin` only after making sure that the code runs in the client side, and for that i imported it inside `useEffect` method and it worked.

here is the code in my case:

```
  useEffect(() => {
      const GSAP = require("gsap/CSSRulePlugin");
      const { CSSRulePlugin } = GSAP;
      gsap.registerPlugin(CSSRulePlugin); 
      // do whatever you want to do with the plugin, its Working now...
      // for example
      let imageReveal = CSSRulePlugin.getRule(".container:after");     
  }, []);
```